# Print maps with a specific scale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, printing

I need to print a map (with Arcgis 10.0) that has an extension of 1200 kmq that formally has a scale of 1:25000.
**Simply I need to print it with that specified scale (1:25000)**  but do not know how.

I've tried to looking on online guides, arcgis guides etc, and tried many options on print setup without success.

Some suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you must do two things:

1) set the page properties to the exact characteristics of your future printed document

2) in ArcMap, you can directly change the scale by writing it in the toolbar, or you can fix it in the dataframe properties (dataframe > extent > fixed scale

However, the problem in your case is that you need 48 m of paper to print your area of interest at 1/25000. So you should create an atlas (e.g. using "data driven pages" toolbar based on a regular grid)

Comment: +1 But I do not understand your calculation. 1200 km² = 35 km x 35 km. To print this area with a scale of  1:25000 you need a paper of 1.4 m x 1.4 m.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that if I select " fixed scale" in the view (and in the print, I've tried with a pdf) i can see only a small portion of map, not the entire.

Comment: @Jens I interpreted the post as a transect of 1200 km of extent, but it would indeed make more sense with 1200 square km.

Comment: @toWGS84 the scale is the ratio between the size on the map and the size on the ground, so it is normal that you only see a small portion of the map. You only have two solutions if you want to entire study area at 1/25000: use a larger paper or split your map in an Atlas.